# Set order by random in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, woocommerce

I want to show my category products order by random. So trying to change it but it doesn’t work.

Only date, menu order, popularity, rating these sort method working. Is there any way to set orderby random work in dart?

```
>  @observable
  Map<String, dynamic> _sort = {
    'key': 'product_list_default',
    'query': {
      'order': 'desc',
      'orderby': 'date', //want to change to random  
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not hard..

If your categories are in a List

> e.g
>
> List categories = [category1, category2, category3]

You can use a method like this

```
//first get a random index that will exist in the category list (in this case 'List categories')

Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(categories.length); //from index 0 to the last index

//now to use the random number to select a category
var randomCategory = categories[randomNumber]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

I’m not a developer, just figured out that code inside products_store.dart file. If I change it to price, rating or popularity it work. If I change it to random it doesn’t work. May I know where I need to implement your answer code in my project file.

Comment: oh.. you don't code, but i don't developers can help with that, as we did not make the application/website, you can contact the Woo-commerce support team via email

Comment: also editing too much of there code might not really be to good